# Access to component by DOM element

Tags: vue.js

Component's template:

```
<template id='someComponentTemplate'>
  <div id="{{ item.id }}">
    <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

List stuff:

```
<someComponent v-for="item in items" :item=item></someComponent>
```

Getting component's element by id

```
var element=document.getElementById('id123');
```

Now I want to get access to exact component object which handles found DOM element. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

In case somebody will need a solution, here it is:

First, you should wrap component's template body into extra tag (like `span` or `div`) for example:

```
<template id='someComponentTemplate'>
  <div>
    <div id="{{ item.id }}">
      <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and then access component object this way:

```
var element=document.getElementById('id123');
var component=element.parentElement.__vue__;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be valid. I'm getting undefined.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is to use [Vue references](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)

In your parent page/component do this:

```
<someComponent ref="id123" v-for="item in items" :item=item></someComponent>
```

Then you can access it in your component methods like so:

```
this.$refs.id123
```

This returns a reference to the `SomeComponent` component.

Comment: I don't think you are right, because 
<someComponent v-for="item in items" :item=item></someComponent>

results in not a single node in DOM, but a bunch of DOM nodes for any item in items array

Comment: exactly this is not correct should be this.$refs.id123[index] to access the component for an item in array of components